# I can't boot Windows 7 USB from macOS Sierra using option key

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, usb, startup, windows

I want to install Windows 7 on my Mac, which is running macOS Sierra.

I can't do this with Boot Camp, since Boot Camp only supports Windows 8 and later.

I need to boot from the USB, which I created, but I can't do it using the usual method of holding down <kbd>option</kbd> key while booting the Mac.

I also tried holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> key, nothing works, it just starts as usual.

How can I actually boot from USB and are there different keys to press in order to boot from USB or boot in safe mode in macOS Sierra?

Comment: To clarify, you're only holding the `Option (Alt)` key on startup, right? Not `Option + Tab`?

Comment: I tried both combinations

Comment: It seems I have confused ALT / Options and TAB, while only holding ALT it works. It doesn't recognize the USB but I get to the booting menu. I think this question should be closed :/

Comment: No worries- glad to hear the boot picker comes up as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> Mac computers using macOS Sierra 10.12 support new installations of
>   Windows 10 only. macOS Sierra does not support new installations of
>   earlier versions of Windows.

See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016 for more information.